# QGIS difference output has same number of features

Tags: qgis, differences

Having a problem with the QGIS Difference feature. Two inputs: a point and a polygon file. I am trying to generate a list of the points that are not covered by the polygons. 
I am using the "use only selected features" option on the point shapefile, as I want only points that are within the US. When I use "only selected", the difference output *looks correct on the map* but my attribute table contains **all** selected entries in the point file!

When I **do not** use the "selected features" option, the attribute table contains only the features that are outside of the polygons (it works correctly). I can then export and filter the list appropriately.

Question:
What am I doing wrong? (if anything)? Why does the map show the correct result, but with entries in the attribute table that are not mapped? Is this a bug that I should report? (Using 2.12.3-Lyon on Win7)

Comment: Are you using difference from the vector menu or from the Processing toolbox?

Comment: Vector>Geoprocessing tools>difference

Comment: Are you looking at the _Attribute Table_ of the **output** point layer? This seems to work for me (I also used QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon on Win7).

Comment: Of course. I'm a noob, but not that green! ;)