# Using QGIS Difference with Point and Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, point, differences

After installing a fresh QGIS 3.10 version on a Windows computer I recently saw an unexpected behavior of the "Difference" feature from QGIS. (on one of my old computer with QGIS 3.4 it is different)
I'm trying to remove points from a layer that falls into a polygon from another layer.
After running the "Difference" model the points that falls into the polygon layer are moved to the x,y position x=0 and y=0.
Has anyone an idea why this happens. My expected output is simple a layer without the points that falls into the polygon.
I want to use the "difference" function because it should be integrated in a bigger model.

Process:

[image: three points]

[image: poly that covers two points]

[image: tree points]

[image: function]

[image: result]

Comment: Select by location instead?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61753/62556

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please don't include thanks (or other chit chat) in questions you ask here.  The way to say thanks here is to upvote (or accept) answers to your questions).

Comment: @GISKid, select by location with the model "Extract by location" and the option "disjoint" solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your particular error, but when I try a similar function in QGIS 3.12.2 with simple shapefile point and polygon data (geometry valid per GEOS), I keep getting `GEOS geoprocessing error: difference failed.` - after a varying length of time depending on the size of the data.

However I have been able to make it run properly with the exact same point and polygon data in QGIS 3.10.5 (English version if that makes a difference)

Both versions are running GDAL version: 3.0.4, GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3, PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.1. No issues with lines/polygons or polygons/polygons or lines/lines in either version.

I think it's a legitimate issue that Difference is not working as expected.

---

However as @GISKid suggested, to solve your specific problem, consider using Select by Location - if you wish to use this in a processing model try Extract by Location and use the `disjoint` spatial predicate (not sure what these are called in German) to return a dataset that you can feed into the next step.

Comment: select by location with the model "Extract by location" and the option "disjoint" solves the problem.

Comment: I have also tested the behavior described above with different configuration. For example with (QGIS 3.6.1 & GDAL 2.4.1) the difference function is working fine for the point layer. When using (QGIS 3.10.5 & GDAL 3.0.4) the behavior is exactly like I'm described above. I'm not sure if the GDAL version is effecting the function because the "Difference" function is a build in function from QGIS and is not using the GDAL Library.

Comment: The behavior was reported several times in the last years: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181948/qgis-difference-output-has-same-number-of-features) and [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263664/points-and-polygons-difference-issue-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

The "GEOS geoprocessing error: difference failed" issue with the "Difference" processing algorithm is now fixed in the developer version QGIS 3.27.0-Master starting from the [5a6b76a](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5a6b76abaffec7acce26e0b412759383c5732832) commit, and will be fixed in the stable versions starting from QGIS 3.26.1 and from QGIS LTR 3.22.10.

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49300.